# Content-Security-Police violation on LastPass in Firefox

Tags: firefox, content-security-policy, lastpass

We have a problem with the LastPass extension on Firefox, at certain moments (we don't know exactly when yet), it blocks us from submitting the form (or it probably blocks onclick). The bad thing is that we can't duplicate the bug, so we don't know exactly what's going on.

However, a message appears in the log console

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”). onloadwff.js:71:798525
```

I thought fixing this bug would help resolve the form issue, but I don't understand the report. The point is that I don't have a Content Security Policy set, and even so, Firefox blocks this script's own extension! I tried to set up my own CSP in Report-Only mode to see some feedback, but no report of this error came. That's strange for me.

Can anyone advise what the problem may be?